# Algorithm removes vowels, unexpected result

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to build an algorithm that removes the vowels from a string. The below code is what I have so far.

```
def shortcut(s)
  s = s.split("")
  for i in 0..s.length - 1 do
    if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(s[i])
      s.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
  s.join
end


puts shortcut("hello world, we are the champions")
# => hll wrld, w r th chmpons
```

Why is the `'o'` not being removed from the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By deleting a character, index become invalid.

```
hello
  ^    before delete
01234
  v    after delete
hllo
```

You can iterate from end to beginning to work around it.

```
def shortcut(s)
  s = s.split("")
  (s.length - 1).downto(0) do |i|
    if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(s[i])
      s.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
  s.join
end
```

But better solution is to use string replacement methods like [`String#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-delete), [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub).

```
"hello world, we are the champions".gsub(/[aeiou]/, '')
=> "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

Answer (score 5):

You are deleting elements from the array `s` while iterating over it. That would give you unexpected result.

Use [`String#delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-delete) instead:

```
"hello world, we are the champions".delete('aeiou')
# => "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

Comment: I appreciate you showing me a new approach to this problem. And that's great, now I know how to do it in a different way. But that still doesn't explain why I'm getting the unexpected result.

Comment: @TodLazarov The reason is my first sentence: *You are deleting elements from the array `s` while iterating over it.*

Comment: @YuHao Strictly speaking, the result is expected: _n_-th letter of the actual string.

Comment: That is correct :) Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

While you're deleting elements from your array, your iterator i can be greater than the size before you reach the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest approach

```
def shortcut(s)
  s.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '')
end

shortcut('hello world, we are the champions')
#=> "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Array#Select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select).

```
def shortcut(s)
  s.chars.select{|s| s !~ /[aeiou]/ }.join('')
end

## OR

def shortcut(s)
  s.chars.select{ |s| s if !["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(s) }.join('')
end

shortcut("hello world, we are the champions")

## OUTPUT
 => "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you study the following simplified example you will understand why deleting elements of the array over which you are iterating caused the result you obtained.

```
s = "two lions"
s = s.split("")
puts "s.split=#{s}"
for i in 0..s.length - 1 do
  puts "i=#{i}"
  str = s[i]
  puts "  str=/#{str}/"
  if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include?(s[i])
    puts "  str is a vowel"
    s.delete_at(i)
    puts "  s after delete_at(#{i})=#{s}"
  end
end
puts "s after loop=#{s}"
puts "s.join=#{s.join}"
s.join
```

prints

```
s.split=["t", "w", "o", " ", "l", "i", "o", "n", "s"]
i=0
  str=/t/
i=1
  str=/w/
i=2
  str=/o/
  str is a vowel
  s after delete_at(2)=["t", "w", " ", "l", "i", "o", "n", "s"]
```

The space is skipped.

```
i=3
  str=/l/
i=4
  str=/i/
  str is a vowel
  s after delete_at(4)=["t", "w", " ", "l", "o", "n", "s"]
```

"o" is now at index 4 and "n" is at index 5.

```
i=5
  str=/n/
i=6
  str=/s/
i=7
  str=//
i=8
  str=//
s after loop=["t", "w", " ", "l", "o", "n", "s"]
s.join=tw lons
```

Answer (score 0):

your method can be

```
def shortcut(s)
  s = s.split("")
  for i in 0..s.length - 1 do
    s.delete(s[i]) if ["a","e","i","o","u"].include? s[i]
  end
  s.join
end


> shortcut("hello world, we are the champions")
=> "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

another way

```
> s = "hello world, we are the champions"
> (s.split("") - s.scan(/[aeiou]/)).join
=> "hll wrld, w r th chmpns"
```

Comment: `compact` is completely meaningless there, unless you expect binary input, in which case you solution fails anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I learned a new method :) Even though it doesnt work in this case.